# Create PDF file with default "zoom to page level" (pdfbox)

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I create a PDF file using pdfbox 2.0. when i open this pdf file in Adobe reader (windows), by default its open with zoom `fit width`.

[image]

What I need pdf file open with default `zoom to page level`.

[image]

My try:
Set zoom level at 100.

```
PDPageXYZDestination dest = new PDPageXYZDestination();    
dest.setPage(pagea);    
dest.setZoom(1);    
dest.setTop(new Float(PDRectangle.A4.getHeight()).intValue());    
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();    
action.setDestination(dest);    
document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```

Comment: `PDPageFitDestination dest = new PDPageFitDestination();` this would help fit the entire page in window. I'm not sure if "zoom to page level" is supported by the PDF specification, I have not even understood what it means. Apparently it shows a full page and a bit more.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr In "Zoom to page level" pdf page manage zoom according to windows resolution. One whole page show at one time...

Comment: Then please try the code line from my comment and tell whether it does what you need... it replaces the 4 first lines of your code.

Comment: It's working... Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PDPageFitDestination instead of PDPageXYZDestination - so your code looks like this now:

```
PDPageFitDestination dest = new PDPageFitDestination();
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();    
action.setDestination(dest);    
document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```