# Set 'Open to page' of pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PdfBox to concatenate pdfs and fill in forms.

However I noticed depending on viewer it scrolls all the way down to the last page. That's something which didn't happen with the legacy tool.

Using Acrobat there's a setting for that:

> [image: Document Properties window]
>   (<kbd>File</kbd> ->
>   <kbd>Properties</kbd> opens "Document Properties" window, <kbd>Initial View</kbd> -> `Open to page` field)

---

Oddly it is often set to the last page of the pdf, instead of the first one.

Question is, how can I modify it to be on the very first page programmatically?

---

**Edit 0**:
I had a look at it with the old pdfdebugger (I used pdfbox `1.8.1`, but any later [`pdfbox-app-1.8.*.jar`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi)  should work as well. (Not `2.*` though))

```sh
java -jar ~/Downloads/pdfbox-app-1.8.1.jar PDFDebugger
```

> [image: pdfbox-app-1.8.1 page scroll element OpenAction]
>   From comparing I'd think I need to set that `OpenAction` somehow

**Edit 1**:
Here is a list of input pages, I read what was entered in this field:

- 1 of 1
- 1 of 1
- 2 of 2
- 1 of 2
- 1 of 2
- 1 of 2
- 1 of 1
- 1 of 4
- 1 of 4
- 1 of 1
- 1 of 1
- 1 of 13
- 1 of 1

---

**Edit 2**: I realized the freshly generated PDF actually has stored 
`2 of 3 (21)`, not `21 of 3 (21)` like in the screenshot above.

---

**Edit 3**: With the code you linked I came up with the following

```java
        int open_on_page = 3;

        if (open_on_page > 1) {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/q/57707237/3423324/#comment101859372_57707237#set-open-to-page-of-pdf
            PDPageXYZDestination page_destination = new PDPageXYZDestination();
            page_destination.setPageNumber(open_on_page);
            PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
            action.setDestination(page_destination);
            pdf_document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
        }
```

But I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination of a GoTo action must be a page dictionary object`.

Comment: Did the source PDFs have such a setting? One of them, none of them, some of them, all of them?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr One of those pages seem to have that set. See **Edit 1** below the question.
I'll see if changing that makes a difference.

Comment: I wonder if the page `2 of 3` (**Edit 2**) is actually coming from that.

Comment: I just did check it another time, and now all of them are page `1 of *`, without any (git) changes to the files

Comment: use `setOpenAction()`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619737/ Note that you need to read question and answer, the answer doesn't contain the page, but the question does.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm not quite sure how to set the page number dynamically though (See **Edit 3**).

Comment: `page_destination.setPageNumber(pdf_document.getPage(open_on_page));` note that `getPage()` expects a 0-based number.