# How to set PDF open page number from PDFMergerUtility

Tags: java, spring, pdfbox, bytestream, pdfmerger

I am merging PDF content using `PDFMergerUtility` in Java.

```java
PDFMergerUtility bundle= new PDFMergerUtility();
bundle.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentService.retrieveData(transaction1);
bundle.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentService.retrieveData(transaction2);
   
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream() 
bundle.setDestinationStream(outputStream);  // setting outputstream
bundle.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
return outputStream.toByteArray();  // returning result
```

But by default it is opening on the last page of PDF when I try to open the resultant PDF. I am not using PDocument for these as
these are entity based documents. Due to this unable to use this below method. Can you please suggest any approach to directly set the    opened page number in `PDFMergerUtility`.

```java
PDPageXYZDestination destination = new PDPageXYZDestination();
destination .setPageNumber(num);
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
action.setDestination(destination );
pdf.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```

Comment: Use setPage(PDPage), not setPageNumber, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619737/create-pdf-file-with-default-zoom-to-page-level-pdfbox

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using pdfMergeUtility.addSource(inputStreamSource); So not able to use PDocument to setPage method. I am using addSource with imputstream. Can you please suggest in this case.

Comment: You will have to use PDDocument. You'd have to save and reopen the PDF, modify then resave.